# Entity Framework, database wide Guid table, insert order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a synchronization framework that uses a global SyncEntity table to keep track of which entities have been updated at what time, meaning we have a global table with a structure something like this:

```
<dbo.SyncEntity>
ID int
EntityType int
EntityGuid uniqueidentifier
```

The EntityType is an enum that corresponds to the specific entity so that we know in which table to look for this entity.
All our tables have an ID (PK) and a GUID.

I have created a Foreign Key constraint from the different Entity tables and to the EntityGuid in the SyncEntity table.

This works perfect for existing data however when we use EntityFramework to insert new data it doesnt insert the data in the "correct" order resulting in an error because the SyncEntity with the required EntityGuid is not yet inserted.

I guess we could add a property SyncEntity on all of our entities however i really dont want to pollute our domain model with that property.

So my question, is there anyway to ensure that specific Entity types are inserted as the first entities?
Or is there anyway to map the relation from Guid (on the specific Entity) to EntityGuid (on SyncEntity) without a navigation property.

Comment: I know that Entity Framework can be set up to use SP's for insertions. Would that be an acceptable option?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways you could potentially alleviate this issue.

First, you could use domain events to recognize that a new entity has been created and raise an event, passing in the entity itself as a parameter and then allow that event to create a new `SyncEntity` insert it and then save it.  This will populate your ID and then you can assign it to the new entity creating the relationship.

Second, you could override the `SaveChanges` method of the `DbContext` to look at added entities and then create a new record for each of them, then assign your new `SyncEntity` Ids to the entity.

Comment: My issue is not with actually creating the SyncEntities, the problem is that even though they are inserted first into the DbContext, they are not actually flushed first to the database server.

Comment: The only way you can control the order is by controlling the instances of the `DbContext` and when `SaveChanges` is called.  For example, the domain event would handle saving both the entities.   `SyncEntity` Created > `SaveChanges` called > `SyncEntity` ID is assigned to child entity > `SaveChanges` called.  Other than that, you would need custom code and EF doesn't offer anything out of the box.  Trigger isn't bad, but depends how much you want to split your business logic between app and db.  Debugging can become more difficult with it split also.

Answer (score 0):

WHy would you bother EF with something like that?

Have the SyncEntity entry created by a trigger on the tables. Finished. EF does not have to bother with it.

And it is save for direct SQL usage, too.

EF is a good tool - though only a very very mediocre ORM. But it is not a solution for everything. DB internal logic, like a logging table, should be handled in the database.

Comment: I simplified our usecase alot, alot more logic and other relations are created with the SyncEntity. But as iam reading the answers there is no way to dictate the insert ordre in EF.

Comment: And I stand by my answer - do not use EF for that. THere is nothing wrongwith ahving this type of logic done in the databae. Use the right tool for the right job.